# Grafico BCG em Python.

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Amigos, existe alguma forma de fazer um gráfico conforme abaixo utilizando Python/Matplotolib? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço a ajuda. Observo que pesquisei um bocado sobre o assunto, mas estou encontrando dificuldade, principalmente na inserção de 2 eixos (x,y), dividindo o grafico em quadrantes. É mais ou menos um grafico BCG.